# Django froala image display error in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, froala

I am new to Djnago and programming. Trying to build a blog, everything done except a wysiwyg editor. Trying froala, but issue is files are uploaded but not displayed and error is thrown.

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/blogapp/blogpost/add/uploads/froala_editor/images/DSC00142.JPG/ 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

How to solve this error? Installed froala with suggestion given in https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with Media_Root, We have to define Media_Root path MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') and then MEDIA_URL.

Its working now.